# td without parent table tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

**HTML:**

```
<td class="tabletd"> text one </td><br>
<td class="tabletd" id="tdSecond"> this is next td</td>
<button onclick="myFunc()">click</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function myFunc() {
    var second    = document.getElementById('tdSecond').innerHTML;
    //var second2 = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[1]; //gives error undefined
    alert(second);
}
```

I cannot make this work. Even there is no effect of css see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/r3QWf/1/). 
But both javascript and css work fine if we use `<li>` without its parent `<ul>`.
And also javascript and css work fine on custom tag. for eg:- `<ddd> text </ddd>`

So why we get error on both css and javascript if we use `<td>` without its parent `<table>` ?

Comment: Because it's invalid HTML. If you use invalid HTML, you're relying on the browser's ability to make sense of it rather than parse it normally.

Comment: @Blender But then why does `<li>` without `<ul>` and made-up tags work fine?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-td-element

Comment: Why would you purposely write invalid markup?

Comment: I just want to know why we get error. I got the answer from @3dgoo, browser don't throw the `td` even we write the code, it just take text so we can't create object of `td` element after.

Comment: The `<td>` tag defines a standard cell **"in an HTML table"**. and The `<li>` tag defines a list item.

Comment: @PankitKapadia That doesn't matter. In the spec, it gives a list of what the "valid" parents are. For `<td>`, it's `<tr>`. For `<li>`, it's `<ul>`, `<ol>`, and `<menu>`. So what does just saying "in an HTML table" matter?

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13947123/821773

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inspect the element in chrome you will notice the code has changed to the following:

```
<body>
    text one <br>
    this is next td
    <button onClick="myFunc()">click</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 

    function myFunc() {
    var second=document.getElementById('tdSecond').innerHTML;
    alert(second);

    //var second2=document.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML;
    //alert(second2);  
    }

    //]]>  

    </script>
</body>
```

The td elements have been stripped by the browser as they are not valid.

Comment: What makes a `<td>` any different from a `<li>` in this situation? A lonely `<li>` is "invalid", but it won't be stripped. Or a made-up tag of `<ddd>`?

Comment: It's a good question. This is up to the discretion of the browser or the rendering kit and I guess they seem to be more anal about `<td>` than `<li>`.

Comment: That's all I was wondering (since the OP asked the question and found this out). Otherwise, that was good work finding it was stripped :)

Comment: Hopefully someone more knowledgeable on this topic can come and enlighten us.

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13947123/821773 and also if you want to read more, this is a link for HTML parsing http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html

Comment: @3dgoo - HTML parser behaviour is informed more by the legacy of what browsers have traditionally done, than by any form of sanity, because modern browsers need to process old web pages the same way that the contemporary browsers did at time the page was written. Different programmers of those old browsers, at different times,  chose different strategies for handling invalid mark-up. There's neither rhyme nor reason, just a whole bunch of specific rules which these days are described in detail at http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#tree-construction

Comment: @Alohci - That makes sense in a stupid way. Thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 5):

This would explain why `<li>` items can be without `<ul>`
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element

> The li element represents a list item. If its parent element is an ol,
>   ul, or menu element, then the element is an item of the parent
>   element's list, as defined for those elements. Otherwise, the list
>   item has no defined list-related relationship to any other li element.
>
> If the parent element is an ol element, then the li element has an
>   ordinal value.

`<ul>` is merely meant to group similar `<li>` items. Without the `<ul>`, a `<li>` is just an individual list item that is not grouped whatsoever. So having a `<li>` without a `<ul>` is still valid markup that the parser will pass.

`<td>` and `<tr>` elements specifically have to reside within a `<table>` element.
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-td-element

This is how tables are formed by the parser and having a `<td>` without a `<table>` will throw a table model error:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#table-model

This test shows:

```
<!-- fail -->
<tr>
  <td>tr_td_test</td>
</tr>

<!-- fail -->
<td>td_test</td>

<!-- pass as a regular list item -->
<li>li_test</li>

<!-- pass and tr tag is added to DOM -->
<table>
  <td>table_td_test 1</td>
</table>

<!-- pass and td tag is added to DOM -->
<table>
  <tr>
    table_tr_test_1
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this.There are html problems. try this html

```
    <table border="1">
<tr>
<td class="tabletd"> text one </td><br>
<td class="tabletd" id="tdSecond"> this is next td</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button onclick="myFunc()">click</button>
```