# Centering checkbox in td (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

First of all, I was searching for solutions, but none of them worked for me, I don't know why.

I want to center a checkbox in a table cell.

My "output" in Chrome:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bkla.png)

My code:

```css
{ 
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:center;
}
```

```html
<td class="align-middle text-center" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 50px;">
 <div class="form-check-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" style="margin-left: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; margin-right: 0px;" name="students[]" id="students" value="{{ $student->id }}">   
    </div>
 </td>
```

I just cannot center it horizontally. I was trying everything what is in style attribute and in CSS `{ text-align: center; vertical-align:center;)`.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the alignment properties to the classes you've defined for the `td` element, and make sure it's wrapped in a table, otherwise the `td` tags will be stripped by the browser (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945982/td-without-parent-table-tag)):

```css
.align-middle { 
  vertical-align:center;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td class="align-middle text-center" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 50px;">
    <div class="form-check-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" style="margin-left: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; margin-right: 0px;" name="students[]" id="students" value="{{ $student->id }}">   
    </div>
  </td>
</table>
```